# Create a read-only user UCD and UCB

Tags: devops, udeploy, urbancode, ucd

I'm trying to create a read-only user at certain applications in urbancode deploy and ubuild, just to monitor some builds and deployments triggered from continous integration process.

Is there any shortcut to this requirement? or do i have to configure everything from scratch, like realms, roles, permissions and team?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a role to do this. You don't need another realm. In configuring the role, you'll specify the permissions that role is allowed (read only for what you want). 
Then, create a team to map to that role. You'll then add the LDAP groups or members to that team. Should only take about 15 minutes to configure.